# Compilation errors to send email with TRIGGER sql

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Hello i'm working on PL/SQL Developper and i've got an annoying error ... I'm trying to make a trigger to send an email when something is added in the "JDEF" database.
This is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Send_Email
AFTER INSERT
ON JDEF
BEGIN 
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
             @profile_name = 'me',
             @recipients = 'example@ent.com',
             @body = 'The stored procedure finished successfully.',
             @subject = 'Automated Success Message'
END
```

The error compilation are for those two lines : EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail AND @profile_name = 'me'. They speak about "MSDB" and ",' symbols who are replaced by other one to compile.

Have you any ideas to help me ?

thx

Comment: That syntax is invalid for Oracle. That is T-SQL (Microsoft) but far from being valid PL/SQL

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your answer, do you have any alternative to propose?

Comment: What happens if the user makes a `ROLLBACK`? In this case the mail will be sent anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like mssql in oracle standard way to send email is for example:

```
UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'me@ent.com',
            recipients => 'example@ent.com',
               subject => 'Automated Success Message',
               message => 'The stored procedure finished successfully.',
             mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii');
```

But it needs being enabled before you can use `UTL_MAIL`. Another package to send mail is `UTL_TCP`
This may be helpful: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL